# Place a Carousel just below the navbar bootstrap-4 Beta

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to place a Bootstrap Carousel just below the navbar with full height. If I remove Bootstrap class fixed-top then Carousel automatically start below the navbar. In this situation what should I do? How can I achieve this task?
Please Check: https://www.codeply.com/go/11JujOx93X

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand p-3" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
    <div class="navbar-nav">
      <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<!-- Carousel -->
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1068989/pexels-photo-1068989.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=650&w=940" alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1068989/pexels-photo-1068989.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=650&w=940" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1068989/pexels-photo-1068989.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=650&w=940" alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

**I want something like this:**
[image: I want something like this:]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1- give the body a padding-top as height as navbar in css :

```
body { padding-top: 60px; }
```

2- its better to do this with jQuery to determine the navbar height :

```
$('body').css('padding-top', $('.navbar').outerHeight());
```

3- if you want to fit carousel + navbar height equal to view height :

```
$('body').css('padding-top', $('.navbar').outerHeight());
var carouselHeight = $('body').height() - $('.navbar').outerHeight();
$('.carousel, .carousel .item, .carousel .carousel-inner').css('height', carouselHeight)
```